# Groovy AST: the order of local and global transformations

Tags: groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I have an AST transformation which runs both as a global and a local one.

The idea is,

1. the **global AST** finds all the classes annotated with `@Entity`
2. the **local AST** is "injecting" a list of found class-names into a new field of a specifically annotated class.

The whole thing works, and unit-tests prove that.

Although, I'm not sure about the **ordering** of local and global ASTs, and couldn't find the info on that in [ref-doc](https://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#developing-ast-xforms).

Is it guaranteed, that the global AST **always** runs before the local one? Is it subject to change in upcoming Groovy 4+ versions?